# WAF deny rule on APIGAteway

Tags: aws-api-gateway

We noticed a couple of scans being performed against our API services. These requests were blocked by AWS WAF however the CloudWatch metrics for AWS API Gateway still showed the following:

1. API Latency were significantly lower due to these invalid requests
2. 4xx error rates were elevated due to this
3. api request had increase in count

Would like to check if the behaviour is as expected

Comment: I think there is something wrong, the firewall should block the requests so they shouldn't get through the API gateway if they are properly denied.

Comment: It is expected behaviour.